# Как считать данные из Excel документа, не открывая его?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Сейчас работает только при открытом файле. Вот такая строка подключения:

```
const string oleConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No\";Data Source={0}";
```

вот так стандартно открываю

```
var oleConnStr = String.Format(oleConn, fileName);

OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(oleConnStr);

cn.Open();
```

Ошибка:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Внешняя таблица не имеет предполагаемый формат.

Comment: Смотрели http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c ?

Comment: Советую к прочтению следующий топик:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb расказано несколько методов взаимодействия с ексель файлами и их плюса/минуса + простенькая либа для работы с ексель файлом как с 2хмерным масивом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не мучаемся и устанавливаем (`Install-Package ExcelDataReader`) [библиотеку](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader). Далее все очень просто:

```
// Создаем поток для чтения.
var stream = File.Open("путь к файлу", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


// В зависимости от расширения файла Excel, создаем тот или иной читатель.

// Читатель для файлов с расширением *.xlsx.
var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

// Читатель для файлов с расширением *.xls.
var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);


// Читаем, получаем DataSet и работаем с ним как обычно.
var result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

// После завершения чтения освобождаем ресурсы.
excelReader.Close();
```

P.S. Если есть необходимость в явном использовании `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, дайте знать.

Answer (score 1):

У меня работает так. Excel даже и открывать не надо. Но нужно подключить библиотеку `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Вот код:

```
public void Excel(DataGridView datagrid)
{
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        var path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
        const string querry = "SELECT * FROM [Лист1$]";
        var conn = new OleDbConnection
        {
            ConnectionString =
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = '" + path + "'" +
                @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0"""
        };
        var fag = new OleDbDataAdapter(querry, conn) {AcceptChangesDuringFill = false};
        fag.Fill((DataTable) _dt1);
        datagrid.DataSource = _dt1;

    }
    else
    {
        ofd.Dispose();
    }
}
```